# How to save changes twice in one method using Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core i am trying to save changes twice for the same entity collection.

```
    public async Task Save(IEnumerable<Request> request)
    {            
        var entities = request.Select(x => new MyEntity()
        {
            FileName = x.FileName,                
            Status = Status.Downloading                
        });

        // save as downloading
        await _dbContext.MyFiles.AddRangeAsync(entities).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // start downloading
        await _storage.DownloadFilesAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // save as downloaded
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            entity.Status = Status.Downloaded;
        }

        // this save DOES NOT update the entities with status Downloaded
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);          
    }
```

The first call to `SaveChanges()` method creates entities in the DB with status `Downloading`.

Then i am modifying entity's status to `Downloaded` and call `SaveChanges()` again. However this time entities does not get updated in DB.

I thought entities are already loaded in the Db context, so i dont have to reload them before second `SaveChanges`. Just modifying the property would mark them modified. But its not working.

**Update 1**
I updated code as below and explicitly set State as Modified

```
 // save as downloaded
 foreach (var entity in entities)
 {
    entity.Status = Status.Downloaded;      

    // The exception occurs at line below on 2nd loop
   _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
 }
```

Now im getting exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
>   'MyEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type
>   with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities,
>   for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no
>   key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for
>   its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities,
>   ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values
>   generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities,
>   ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is
>   attached to the context.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey
>   key, InternalEntityEntry entry)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry
>   entry)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState
>   oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges)

The entity has `Id` property of type `int` and The `Id` property also has `[Key]` attribute.

```
public class MyEntity
{
   [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string FileName {get;set;}
   public string Status {get;set;}
}
```

**Update 2**
So after doing little more debugging, i found the first `SaveChanges()` operation is creating the records in the database and also assigning unique Ids to each record as expected. The `Id` is auto incremented identity column in the database.
However the entities are not refreshed with new Ids. so all the entities still have value 0 after first savechanges.

How do i refresh these entities with newly created Ids?

Inside `foreach` loop i tried reloading as

```
   _dbContext.Entry<OcrFile>(entity).ReloadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

but that didn't refresh.

Comment: Have you tried marking the entity state as modified? `_dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: @Steve How does _dbContext match the instance, how _dbContext would know which entity to mark as modified?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!!. I have to eagerly load entities using `ToList()` or `ToArray()` before i pass them to `AddRange` method

```
    var entities = request.Select(x => new MyEntity()
    {
        FileName = x.FileName,                
        Status = Status.Downloading                
    }).ToList();
```

I am not sure that is a bug in EF but i created a separate [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147035/addrange-method-does-not-refresh-id-with-ienumerable) for that question

Comment: It's not a bug, in order to EF deal with entities and track them, they need to be materialized, e.g., call .ToList() or .FirstOrDefault() etc.