# Adding entities using AddRange method does not refresh entity ID

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using `EF Core 1.1.1`. I have noticed when i add `IEnumerable<Entity>` using `AddRange` method and then call `SaveChanges()` then entities gets saved in the database however their ID does not get refreshed.

Code below **does not** refresh ID after SaveChanges(). Note i am passing requests as `IEnumerable`

```
    public async Task Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        var requests = values.Select(x => new Test()
        {
            Name = x,
            Status = "Init"
        });

        await _dbContext.Tests.AddRangeAsync(requests).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        foreach (var r in requests)
        {
            var id = r.ID;
        }
    }
```

Code below **does not** refresh ID after SaveChanges(). Note i am passing `request.ToList()` as a parameter to `AddRange` method

```
    public async Task Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        var requests = values.Select(x => new Test()
        {
            Name = x,
            Status = "Init"
        });

        await _dbContext.Tests.AddRangeAsync(requests.ToList()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        foreach (var r in requests)
        {
            var id = r.ID;
        }
    }
```

Code below **does** refresh ID after SaveChanges(). Note I am calling `ToList()` after selecting values.

```
    public async Task Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        var requests = values.Select(x => new Test()
        {
            Name = x,
            Status = "Init"
        }).ToList();   //<------ ToList() or ToArray() would work

        await _dbContext.Tests.AddRangeAsync(requests).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        foreach (var r in requests)
        {
            var id = r.ID;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if this is a bug in EF or this is how it supposed to work. I understand `IEnumerable` is `lazy` and `List` and `Array` are `eager`, but if `AddRange` method is taking `IEnumerable` as parameter then it should work regardless.

Comment: It's not EF Core fault. In the *"not working"* cases you are just `foreach`-ing **new** `Test` objects.

Comment: Thanks for saving my life! Did you find a fix for this? I'm currently using ef core 2.0 and this problem persists, at least with your solution I can retrieve the ids. @LP13

Comment: Ditto! This is really helpful. Still seeing this in EF Core 2.1 but .ToArray() works. Would like to know why this is happening tho.

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan states the reason you are not seeing the id's is that in the Non working cases you are enumerating new test objects.

If you place a break point inside the enumerable you will see that during your for each it creates new Test objects at that time. These are NOT the same objects that were place in the database.

You are actually enumerating the IEnumerable twice

```
public async Task Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    var requests = values.Select(x => { 
        
        //place break point here
        new Test()
        {
            Name = x,
            Status = "Init"
        }
    });

    await _dbContext.Tests.AddRangeAsync(requests.ToList()).ConfigureAwait (false);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    foreach (var r in requests)
    {
        var id = r.ID;
    }
}
```